# Problem with mapping an array obtained by a component in React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm a newbie with React, and I'm trying to understand some basic concepts. Here's my problem:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

const appkey = 'xxxxxx';

class Message extends React.Component {

    state = { 
        data: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Toronto,CA&appid=${appkey}`)
        .then(data => data.json())
        // .then((data) => {
        //  console.log(data);
        // })
        .then(data => this.setState({data}))

    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("The component just updated")
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.data);
        return (

            <div>
            {this.state.data.map(weather => {
                return (
                    <div key={weather.id}>
                    <h3>Library Product of the Week!</h3>
                    <h4>{weather.name}</h4>
                    <h4>{weather.main.temp}</h4>
                    <h4>{weather.main.feels_like}</h4>
                    <h4>{weather.main.temp_min}</h4>
                    <h4>{weather.main.temp_max}</h4>
                    <h4>{weather.main.pressure}</h4>
                    <h4>{weather.main.humidity}</h4>
                    </div>
                    )
            })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

render(
    <Message />, 
    document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

My favorite way is to show the content first then explain the problem.

Like you can see, I use the Openweathermap api just to create some data to show in a component.

It works, I was able to console.log the result then the idea is to map the result to show in an html markup. The problem is that I'm receiving an error which was this.state.data.map is not a function. I'm not 100% sure on why it is not working because it supposes to be an array, any idea?

Plus, for some reason the console.log(this.state.data) will produce the same result three times, the first time the data array will be empty, the second and the third the data is like it is supposed to be.

Comment: the response you are getting may not be an array to `map`. Can you post what is your `console.log` is showing?

Comment: The first time it will show an empty array [], then the real array

coord: {lon: -79.42, lat: 43.7}
weather: [{…}]
base: "stations"
main: {temp: 272.91, feels_like: 266.7, temp_min: 270.15, temp_max: 275.37, pressure: 1026, …}
visibility: 14484
wind: {speed: 5.7, deg: 60}
clouds: {all: 90}

Comment: Looks like `data` is an object then, and `{}.map()` minimally gives you your error. I think you want `setState({data: data.weather})`?

Comment: Agree, we need to see exactly what the shape of this.state.data is after data population. It's definitely not an array, as Array.map will definitely exist. Maybe your array is one level deeper. Data is an object, containing an array you want to map over. @ggorlen is almost definitely correct, but we can't confirm that until we see the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you are getting is an object and `map` does not work on objects. You would need to convert that to array to maps it. You can use `concat` function.

`[].concat(this.state.data).map` should work.

Try Bellow

```
{[].concat(this.state.data).map(weather => {
            return (
                <div key={weather.id}>
                <h3>Library Product of the Week!</h3>
                <h4>{weather.name}</h4>
                <h4>{weather.main.temp}</h4>
                <h4>{weather.main.feels_like}</h4>
                <h4>{weather.main.temp_min}</h4>
                <h4>{weather.main.temp_max}</h4>
                <h4>{weather.main.pressure}</h4>
                <h4>{weather.main.humidity}</h4>
                </div>
                )
        })}
        </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `this.state.data` is a simple object, why first wrap it into an array (with just one element) and then iterate over that? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Since `map` expects an array only, `[].concats()` wraps whole object around array which then can be iterated using `map`. This is one of the simplest way to convert object to array and then iterate it.

Comment: Yes, but why? Just to iterate over that array in order to get the only item we put in there out again? That's horrible!

Comment: I don't understand when you say `only item`. `[].concats({object})` will actually iterate through all the objects wrapped in an array.

Comment: `> [].concat(obj)` results in `[ obj ]` for any object `obj`, and `this.state.data` is a single object, so you'll end up with a singleton array.

Answer (score 1):

According to the demo in their documentation https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather returns JSON of the form:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762037,"sunset":1485794875},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

So yes, absolutely not an array. So you can actually simplify your code:

```js
render() {
  console.log(this.state.data);
  const weather = this.state.data;
  if (weather && weather.main) {
    return (  
      <div>
        <div key={weather.id}>
          <h3>Library Product of the Week!</h3>
          <h4>{weather.name}</h4>
          <h4>{weather.main.temp}</h4>
          <h4>{weather.main.feels_like}</h4>
          <h4>{weather.main.temp_min}</h4>
          <h4>{weather.main.temp_max}</h4>
          <h4>{weather.main.pressure}</h4>
          <h4>{weather.main.humidity}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (<div>loading..</div>);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is my fav answer, but the main. feels_like will return an error, even if it is an object:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {temp, feels_like, temp_min, temp_max, pressure, humidity}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: weather.main.feels_like won't work neither weather.main[feels_like]. How come?

Comment: ah, sorry, I had to also remove the return, which is no longer necessary. Code updated.

Comment: It is still not working.. This Element

{temp: 274.3, feels_like: 271.37, temp_min: 272.15, temp_max: 276.48, pressure: 1026, …}
temp: 274.3
feels_like: 271.37
temp_min: 272.15
temp_max: 276.48
pressure: 1026
humidity: 97
__proto__: Object

is not accessible in this way weather.main.temp. 

It gives an undefined error.. but why??

Comment: Perhaps that's at the beginning before the data is loaded? I've added a guard.

Comment: Indeed, if I console.log the object I obtain two result, one empty array and then a normal array with the result